# Can't remove all childNodes

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all childNodes with `class="child"` from their parentNode, but only odd sequence is removed. How can I remove all elements with `class="child"` in native javascript and why only odd sequence is removed?

```js
var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

function remove(){
  for (var i=0; i<child.length; i++) {
    child[i].parentNode.removeChild(child[i]);
  }
}
document.getElementById("del").onclick = remove;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 3
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 4
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 5
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 6
  </div>
</div>

<button id="del">Remove Child</button>
```

Comment: the variable `i` does not point to the parent's children properly

Comment: check my answer Slaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a NodeList, which is an array-like object that presents a live view of the results.

As you remove the class from those elements, the elements are removed from the NodeList.

When you remove the class from `child[0]`, `child` shrinks, and `child[0]` becomes the next element.

There are a number of ways to fix this:

- Copy the NodeList to an array so that it doesn't change underneath you (eg, `child = Array.prototype.slice.call(child)`)
- Loop backwards so you aren't affected by the changing indices
- Always remove the class from `child[0]` until the NodeList is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but why if I use `querySelectorAll(".child")` all `class="child` can be removed?

Comment: there is no need for all this mess ... just check my answer.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: Your answer is exactly my third solution.  Also, it's important to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @agus-putra-dana: Because `querySelectorAll` returns a list that is **not** live. I.e. removing an element from the document does *not* change the list.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: The *"all this mess"* is a more thorough explanation of the problem and overview of the solutions that which you've provided in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer using `querySelector`

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll('div .child');
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    children[i].parentNode.removeChild(children[i]);
```

Comment: @SLaks: Actually it does, because `children` is not live. Of course if the answer had an **explanation**, it would be more obvious and helpful. But who doesn't like vague answers?

Comment: although I dig `querySelector` it's worth mention that the performance is lower than the `getElementsByClassName` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean ...

```js
var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

function remove(){
  var l = child.length;
  for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
    child[0].parentNode.removeChild(child[0]);
  }
}
document.getElementById("del").onclick = remove;
```

```html
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 3
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 4
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 5
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 6
  </div>
</div>

<button id="del">Remove Child</button>
```

Comment: @agus-putra-dana: There is no need to store `child.length`; just check whether it's non-zero, and don't use a `for` loop at all.

Comment: yeah you can use a `while` if you prefer

Comment: @agus-putra-dana: Be careful with this. People implement shims for browsers like IE8 that don't support `getElementsByClassName`. The shim doesn't return a live list, causing this solution to fail. A reverse iteration is a safer approach since any potentially removed item is always "behind" the rest of the iteration..

Answer (score 0):

> One has dynamic changed in DOM tree,another one doesn't.

```js
function querySelectorDelete(){
    var box2 = document.querySelector("#box1").querySelectorAll(".box2");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(box2,function(el){
        el.remove();
    })
}
function getElementsDelete(){
    var box2 = document.getElementById("box1").getElementsByClassName("box2");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(box2,function(el){
        el.remove();
    })
}
```

```css
#box1{width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;color:#fff;}
.box2{width:50px;height:50px;background:red;margin:5px;}
.box3{width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;margin:5px;}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <div class="box2">first</div>
  <div class="box2">second</div>
  <div class="box2">third</div>
  <div class="box3">
    <div class="box2">forth</div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="querySelectorDelete()">Delete Box2</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="getElementsDelete()">Delete Box2</button>
</div>
```